# Django DATABASES settings

Tags: django

I understand if you connect to your `MongoDB` database via `pymongo`, you should remove the `DATABASES` section in your `settings.py` file, which I have done, but I get this:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value.
```

Apparently, `pymongo` does not replace a relational database with `MongoDB`. It is simply a facility allowing you to access a `MongoDB` in addition to your regular database; meaning I still need my databases settings...

I know my **connection string** and **database name** and **collection name**, but what should the `DATABASES` section look like in my `settings.py` file?

On https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases and a few other posts and articles, only settings for `sqlite3` and `postgresql` and `mysql` and `oracle` are mentioned. I cannot seem to find the right setting for `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mongodb'`

How can I use a `MongoDB` database then? What goes in the `xxx.backends.xxx` section?

I have tried the following, but I get the same error:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': '',
        'NAME': 'myDBname',
        'USER': 'myUser',
        'PASSWORD': 'myPass',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '8000',
    }
}
```

When the method in my `views.py` file is invoked, control does go into the method but I get an `GET http://localhost:8000/methodname/ 500 (Internal Server Error)` error.

Comment: As far as I know, Django depends on a relational database. You'll need ot use one of the SQL databases mentioned in the documentation, `sqlite` is the most lightweight one. You can use Mongo in addition if you want.

Comment: @Flimm I have another question that is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70350583/django-and-angular-communication-failure). I wanted to post my question, but I wonder if you would know the issue in that post, so I won't ask a duplicate question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django depends on a relational database. You'll need to use one of the SQL databases mentioned in the documentation, sqlite is the most lightweight one. You can use Mongo in addition if you want.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [djongo](https://github.com/nesdis/djongo). It actually created to connect Django projects to mongodb.

Also in [mongodb](https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/mongodb-and-django) official documentation you can read about how to configure and connect to your local or remote db using djongo.

Comment: Thank you Salvat0re. I will try `djongo` in a different project. Here, I just needed to get it working with `pymongo`.